# NodeJs Express passport-jwt getting wrong user from token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, token, passport.js

I have setup an auth api on node server, using passportjs as my middleware and passport-jwt as my strategy.

**My passport.js file**

```
let JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy,
  ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;

// load up the user model
let User = require("../models/user");
let config = require("../config/database"); // get db config file

module.exports = function (passport) {
  var opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt");
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(opts, function (jwt_payload, done) {
      User.findOne({ id: jwt_payload.id }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
          done(null, user);
        } else {
          done(null, false);
        }
      });
    })
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this : change

```
User.findOne({ id: jwt_payload.id },
```

to

```
User.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload._id },
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're searching by objectId you can use

```
User.findById(jwt_payload.id);
```